# What specifically is the gap in Aubin's argument about positive Ricci curvature that Paul Ehrlich alludes to?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, ricci-curvature

In his paper [2], Paul Ehrlich write

> In [1], Aubin stated a theorem which implied as a corollary that ***if a manifold
> $M$ admits a Riemannian metric with nonnegative Ricci curvature and
> all Ricci curvatures positive at some point, then $M$ admits a metric of everywhere
> positive Ricci curvature.*** It appears the proof in [1] is incomplete
> and the uniformity and correctness of Aubin's estimates even in the compact
> case are not clear.

Aubin paper is a bit technical so I want to know did Paul Ehrlich have a valid point, and if so, what is it, specifically?

What specifically is the gap in Aubin's argument about positive Ricci curvature that Paul Ehrlich alludes to?

**Note 1:** As far as I understand main part of the proof of wanted theorem is in pp. 397-399.

**Note 2:** Most of people that cited Aubin's paper (about positive Ricci curvature), also cited Paul Ehrlich's paper as well. Note also that most of papers that referred to Aubin's paper is because of results about scalar curvature and Yamabe problem.

---

[1]: *Aubin, T.*, [**Métriques riemanniennes et courbure**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214429638), J. Differ. Geom. 4, 383-424 (1970). [ZBL0212.54102](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0212.54102).

[2]: *Ehrlich, Paul*, [**Metric deformations of curvature. I: Local convex deformations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00145952), Geom. Dedicata 5, 1-23 (1976). [ZBL0345.53024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0345.53024).

Comment: Perhaps this is too tautological, but do you see people citing [1] in a substantial way, in the literature?   A MathSciNet search could give you a first approximation as to how internalized the result is, in the literature, which is a gauge of how accepted a paper is.   As you probably know "is this result correct" questions tend to not always get favorable treatment here.

Comment: @RyanBudney: Most of people cited Aubin paper, also cited Paul Ehrlich's paper as well. This makes me hesitate that perhaps others also have same problem of Paul Ehrlich. (I have no access to MathSciNet but I checked ZB).

Comment: @RyanBudney: FWIW, I think "is this result in a paper from the 70s correct" is pretty different from "is this result in a preprint that was posted to the arXiv yesterday correct," and doubly so if there is another published paper casting doubts on the result.

Comment: @SamHopkins: The 70's is an era where there were a lot of prominent papers with big holes in them.  While I would certainly enjoy having a venue where we point out the problems in those papers, maybe there needs to be a meta discussion before we open  up the floodgates?

Comment: @RyanBudney: Maybe there should be a meta discussion. In my opinion, if the paper is more than a handful of years old, and you can either: point to a specific potential issue with the argument; or point to a public statement of doubt from someone else, then asking about the correctness of the paper is totally fine for MO. (These qualifiers eliminate 90% of the bad faith questions about new purported proofs of the Riemann hypothesis or whatever...)

Comment: I did a little search.  It appears the consensus is that the question-asker should not post a question about correctness of a paper, but instead read the paper and ask specific questions about a specific step in the paper. https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1265/using-math-overflow-to-check-whether-or-not-a-proof-is-correct

Comment: I've put together a meta thread: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5390/questions-about-correctness-of-published-papers

Comment: @RyanBudney: Why you say  "_The 70's is an era where there were a lot of prominent papers with big holes in them_"? Do you aware of another paper with deficient proof? It seems that you are agree with Paul Ehrlich?

Comment: during the classification of finite simple groups (CFSG) effort, in the 70s-80s, there were a number of not too correct papers in this areas. And CFSG was declared complete on basis on a never published hundreds pages long preprint.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: Are you sure? I think nowadays CFSG has been confirmed by computers but I am not sure. In any case how can one  trust such results?

Comment: no, CFSG has not been confirmed by computers. Some parts of it, yes, but only the easiest ones.

Comment: a complete proof of CFSG is still way too long, and very few active researchers understand most details. A revision of the proof is ongoing, but worryingly mostly by people in their 70s. Anyhow, a paper might claim a correct result, but with an incorrect or incomplete proof.